# Capacitive sensor - How to activate with a portable device

Tags: capacitive

I'd like to activate a capacitive sensor - a smartphone touch screen for instance - with an electronic device - say an Arduino board. Basically I'd like to reproduce [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Plays-Stick-Hero/?ALLSTEPS), but with one more condition: I want my Arduino to be powered on battery, so with no GND. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: it is done on mobiles so it depends on your awareness of dealing with CM stray noise to filter only the target signal

Comment: You don't need really ground to activate the capacitive sensor. You can reproduce the same instructable using battery. The negative terminal of battery just serves as ground for capacitive sensor.. It's the same case for your smartphone too.